# Discord Python quote selector

Tags: python

So I am trying to make a random quote selector.
You say the command and it picks a quote.
Now I am stupid but this is what I have.
Can I get some help on it?

````
@client.command(pass_context = True, aliases=["OSQ"])
async def Obvious_Scout_Quote(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'"Hey! Look! You shape shifted into a dead guy!"') or (f"I am owning you, you fat, bald, fatty fat... fat fat!")```
````

Comment: You want a random quote, so, import the `random` module. Store all your quotes in a list. [Then use `random.choice` to select a quote from the list.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)

Comment: You should learn Python before making a discord bot. [Here](https://docs.python-guide.org/intro/learning/) are some resources to start you off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module built into python to pick a random item from a list:

```
import random

quotes = ["Hey! Look! You shape shifted into a dead guy!", "I am owning you, you fat, bald, fatty fat... fat fat!"]

await ctx.send(random.choice(quotes))
```